# How is an integer stored in C program?

Tags: c

is the number 1 stored in memory as 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a[3] = {1, 1, 0x7f7f0501};
    int *p = a;
    printf("%d %p\n", *p, p);
    p = (long long)p + 1;
    printf("%d %p\n", *p, p);
    char *p3 = a;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++, p3++)
    {
        printf("%x %p\n", *p3, p3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is `16777216` printed in the output:

[image: output]

Comment: If you’re using `lldb` or `gdb` debugger after hitting a breakpoint in your main you can use `x a` to see for yourself. `x` being a shorthand for `read memory` debugger command.

Comment: @Kamil.S -- technically `x` is shorthand for *examine*. Also helpful is the text UI which after hitting the breakpoint you can see all registers and instructions by typing `layout asm` and `layout regs`.

Comment: `"why 16777216 printed?"` How many bytes does the format-specifier `"%d"` print? Suggest Enabling Warnings (e.g. gcc `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` or for VS `/W3`) and fix the warnings.

Answer (score 2):

An integer is stored in memory in different ways on different architectures. Most commons ways are called little-endian and big-endian byte ordering.

See [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

```
                (long long)p+1
                     |
                     v
Your memory: [0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, ...]
```

You increment p not like pointer but as a long long number, so it does not point to next integer but the next byte. So you will get 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 which translates to 0x1000000 (decimal 16777216) in a little-endian arch.

Comment: Now since *type* controls pointer-arithmetic and a `long long` is 8-bytes, wouldn't  `(long long)p + 1` point to the next `long long` 8-bytes after the first? If you want to examine individual bytes, you need to use a type that is 1-byte long, such as `uint8_t` or `char` or `unsigned char`. Then `p + 1` would point to the next byte.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it is casted to an integer type with (long long), so it will increase by one. If the cast was a `(long long *)`, than it will point to 8 bytes ahead of orginal p (given long long is 8 bytes).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Isn't that a cast to `long long` instead of a cast to `long long*`? That plus 1 is not pointer arithmetic. Is it?

Comment: Caveat, technically `(long long)p` creates an integer from the pointer (which the compiler will warn about). Presuming pointers and `long long` are both 8-bytes, that would give you the address of the next byte as you show, albeit in a rather unusual way.

Comment: @Yunnosch - yes, thank you, I caught that when I decided to compile it. Direct address manipulation by casting pointer to integer, good for educational fun, but I suspect there would be more than a number of frowns if that ended up in somebody's production code. (not to mention the number of casts needed to silence the warnings, masking any errors in type or size from the compiler....)

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu sen bu konuyu anlamışsın ihtiyar +1

Answer (score 2):

Something to play with (assuming `int` is 32 bits wide):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef union byte_rec {
    struct bit_rec {
        bool b0 : 1;
        bool b1 : 1;
        bool b2 : 1;
        bool b3 : 1;
        bool b4 : 1;
        bool b5 : 1;
        bool b6 : 1;
        bool b7 : 1;
    } bits;
    unsigned char value;
} byte_t;

typedef union int_rec {
    struct bytes_rec {
        byte_t b0;
        byte_t b1;
        byte_t b2;
        byte_t b3;
    } bytes;
    int value;
} int_t;

void printByte(byte_t *b)
{
    printf(
        "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d  ", 
        b->bits.b0,
        b->bits.b1,
        b->bits.b2,
        b->bits.b3,
        b->bits.b4,
        b->bits.b5,
        b->bits.b6,
        b->bits.b7
    );
}

void printInt(int_t *i)
{
    printf("%p: ", i);
    printByte(&i->bytes.b0);
    printByte(&i->bytes.b1);
    printByte(&i->bytes.b2);
    printByte(&i->bytes.b3);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
    int_t i1, i2;
    
    i1.value = 0x00000001;
    i2.value = 0x80000000;

    printInt(&i1);
    printInt(&i2);

    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x7ffea0e30920: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
0x7ffea0e30924: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

---

**Additional** (based on the comment of @chqrlie):

I've previously used the `unsigned char` type, but the C Standard allows only 3 - and since C99 - 4 types. Additional implementation-defined types may be acceptable by the C Standard and it seems that gcc was ok with the `unsigned char` type for the bit field, but i've changed it nevertheless to the allowed type `_Bool` (since C99).

**Noteworthy**: The order of bit fields within an allocation unit (on some platforms, bit fields are packed left-to-right, on others right-to-left) are undefined (see **Notes** section in the reference).

Reference to bit fields: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field

Comment: sen de bu konuyu anlamışsın ihtiyar +1

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire ihtiyar? No, i 'feel' young :)

Comment: The code seems to work as you expect, but be aware that the C Standard does not guarantee this behavior: neither the bit order nor the absence of padding are specified for the bit-field definitions of type `byte_t`.

Comment: @chqrlie I've added some more info to my answer, especially the order of bit fields, but i'm not sure if we really have a padding issue here?

Answer (score 0):

`p = (long long)p + 1;` is bad code (*undefined behavior* UB (e.g. bus fault and re-booted machine)) as it is not specified to work in C.  The attempted assigned of the newly formed address is not certainly aligned to `int *` needs.

Don`t do that.

---

To look at the bytes of `a[]`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dump(size_t sz, const void *ptr) {
  const unsigned char *byte_ptr = (const unsigned char *) ptr;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
    printf("%p %02X\n", (void*) byte_ptr, *byte_ptr);
    byte_ptr++;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned int a[3] = {1, 1, 0x7f7f0501u};
  dump(sizeof a, a);
}
```

As this is wiki, feel open to edit.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple instances of undefined behavior in your code:

- in `printf("%d %p\n", *p, p)` you should cast `p` as `(void *)p` to ensure `printf` receives a `void *` as it expects. This is unlikely to pose a problem on most current targets but some ancien systems had different representations for `int *` and `void *`, such as early Cray systems.
- in `p = (long long)p + 1`, you have implementation defined behavior converting a pointer to an integer and implicitly converting the integral result of the addition back to a pointer. More importantly, this may create a pointer with incorrect alignment for accessing `int` in memory, resulting in undefined behavior when you dereference `p`.  This would cause a bus error on many systems, eg: most RISC architectures, but by chance not on intel processors. It would be safer to compute the pointer as `p = (void *)((intptr_t)p + 1);` or `p = (void *)((char *)p + 1);` albeit this would still have undefined behavior because of alignment issues.

> is the number 1 stored in memory as 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000?

Yes, your system seems to use little endian representation for `int` types. The least significant 8 bits are stored in the byte at the address of `a`, then the next least significant 8 bits, and so on. As can be seen in the output, `1` is stored as `01 00 00 00` and `0x7f7f0501` stored as `01 05 7f 7f`.

> Why is 16777216 printed in the output?

The second instance of `printf("%d %p\n", *p, p)` as undefined behavior. On your system, `p` points to the second byte of the array `a` and `*p` reads 4 bytes from this address, namely `00 00 00 01` (the last 3 bytes of `1` and the first byte of the next array element, also `1`), which is the representation of the `int` value `16777216`.

To dump the contents of the array as bytes, you should access it using a `char *` as you do in the last loop. Be aware that `char` may be signed on some systems, causing for example `printf("%x\n", *p3);` to output `ffffff80` if `p3` points to the byte with hex value `80`. Using `unsigned char *` is recommended for consistent and portable behavior.